# [EDB-ID: 45411]WordPress Plugin Survey & Poll 1.5.7.3 setting page not showing problem

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, survey, edb

*This is being written using Google Translator.
I am currently conducting a mock experiment following EDB-ID:45411.
This vulnerability is that there is SQL injection of cookies in WordPress Plugin Survey & Poll version 1.5.7.3 or lower. I ran into a problem while following this.

My environment is Windows 7 x64 (or Windows 10 x64) with Apache 2.4.58, php-7.1.7, MariaDB 10.2.7, and WordPress V4.9.8.
I was able to download the plug-in 1.5.7.3 from the vulnerability site (https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/45411). (The version is not currently distributed, and the problem I am talking about is the same in all versions. It works well.)

The problem occurs when you activate the plugin and go to [Settings > WP Survey & Poll] in the WordPress menu to create a survey page.

The error message confirmed through F12->Console is as follows:
load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.8:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
options-general.php:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

From the second time, the error message changes to the following.
load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.8:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wp_sap:1 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wp_sap net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

So, I can't even try creating the survey page because the page doesn't load properly... why?

I tried disabling the firewall
I tried clearing the cache
I tried reinstalling php, apache, etc.
I tried deleting the tables in the database.
I tried resetting the TCP/IP settings and
(Netsh winsock reset
Netsh int ip reset
Ipconfig /release
ip/config /renew
ipconfig /flushdns)
I tried using different versions of the plugin.
I deleted another plugin.
It's the same as the default theme
I tried the same thing in Windows 10 and 7.
I tried it in both Explorer and Chrome.
Edit the wp-config.php file and add define('WP_DEBUG', true); or define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

Did I miss something?
What more can I do?
Is this a problem with the plugin itself (since other versions don't work the same)?

If this doesn't work, we need to come up with another alternative as soon as possible (in a week?).
If the project is hopeless, are there similar vulnerabilities that could serve as an alternative? (As simple as possible? This was just to get used to it by testing out a vulnerability in WordPress and defending against it if I could...)

Comment: Also I use VMware workstation 16

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.